# How to Add Active Class to a Navigation Menu Based on URL in each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a navigation menu on top of my website .that li's content many pages with different urls. How to Add Active Class to a Navigation Menu Based on URL that in each page display it with a specific color?

```
<ul>
<li class="red"><a href="home">HOme</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery">gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `.addClass("active);` to add class named `active` to the link clicked.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will be useful

HTML

```
<ul id="menuList">
<li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery">gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('#menuList li').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); //Remove this in your main code
    $('#menuList li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

CSS

```
.active{
    background-color:green;
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uhjwpvs0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Give a class or ID to the `ul`. Then, assuming jQuery and an ID of `nav`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

All you need then is to style the `.active` class. Also, this assumes your links are `/my-page`, so if you are currently in `my-page`, the link will become `.active`.